# How can i pass parameters to a partial view using jquery method .load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, load, asp.net-mvc-partialview

How can i pass parameters to a partial view using jquery method .load() , i have this function

```
 var str;
    var x;
    x = $("#whereQuery");
    str = x.attr("value");
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        $('#budgetsKey').dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Clave presupuestal de ingresos",
            width: 550,
            minWidth: 400,
            maxWidth: 650,
            show: "slide",
            hide: "slide",
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            open: function(event, ui) {
            //Load the CreateAlbumPartial action which will return 
            // the partial view _CreateAlbumPartial
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Prueba2")", { str: str});
        }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and in my controller i have this

```
 public PartialViewResult Prueba2(String str)
    {
        List<PTI_IncomeBudgetTransference> incomeBudgetTransferenceList;
        cmp_Company = this.masterService.company.GetById(1);
        //Recupera las cuentas por pagar por autorizar
        incomeBudgetTransferenceList = siagService.incomeBudgetTransference.GetAll(this.cmp_Company.CMP_ID, "Pendiente de Autorización");
        return PartialView("Prueba2", incomeBudgetTransferenceList);
    }
```

and i need that "str" to execute a query in my controller, but how can i send it to my action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this in your open handler

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("Prueba2", new { str = str})');
```

Comment: can you try with = instead of : in the routevalues object?

Comment: Noup i try, and still nothing

Comment: I just tried loading som content to a div on a click using  $("#aaaaa").load('@Url.Action("Index", new { str= "something"})'); and it worked just fine.

Comment: Hey man this is working, but when i try to pass the value of this

        str = x.attr("value");


i do this:
       $(this).load('@Url.Action("Prueba2", new { str= str})');
and this:
       $(this).load('@Url.Action("Prueba2", new { str=  x.attr("value")})');

but doesnt work

Comment: try x.val() if it is a jquery object

Comment: this is how i have it:

  open: function (event, ui) {
                var x;
                x = $("#whereQuery");
                
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action("Prueba2", new { str=  x.val()})');

and my browser throw this error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Comment: i use this to send paramaters from jquery variables, i do this and works fine: 

$(this).load('@Url.Action("Prueba2")', { str: x.val() });

But your answer was very helpful, thanks again :) !

Answer (score 2):

This Would be work too.

```
`$("#divForPartialView").load("/HelloWorld/GetAwesomePartialView",
  { param1: "hello", param2: 22},function (){/do other cool client side stuff}
```

);`

Answer (score 1):

It works only if you know the string, in my case string is a client side variable so I change the code into as follow and it worked:

$(this).load('@Url.Action("Prueba2"') + '/' + str);